# What can be a possible algorithm for this?

Tags: c++, algorithm

> SmallR is an archer. SmallR is taking a match of archer with Zanoes. They try to shoot in the target in turns, and SmallR shoots first. The probability of shooting the target each time is `a/b` for SmallR while  for Zanoes it is `c/d`. The one who shoots in the target first should be the winner.
>
> Output: the probability that SmallR will win the match.
>
> Input:
>   A single line contains four integers . a b c d
>
> Output:
>   Print a single real number, the probability that SmallR will win the match.
>
> The answer will be considered correct if the absolute or relative error doesn't exceed 10 - 6.

I thought of how to solve this, but then, how can I calculate the exact probability? It somehow didn't strike me.

```
Eg: input
1 2 1 2
output
0.666666666667
```

Comment: I'm confused about this question.

Comment: "The probability of shooting the target each time is for SmallR while for Zanoes."  What does this mean?

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited to math.stackexchange.com since the question isn't about how to code it, but about the algorithm.

Comment: @JohnPirie maybe it comes from google translate?

Comment: I have added the explanation.

Comment: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/312/B Cmon man, do your homework yourself

Comment: But I couldn't understand the reason given in the tutorial part. That is, `let p=a/b,q=(1-c/d)*(1-a/b). The answer of this problem can be showed as:p*q^0+p*q^1+p*q^2+………… That is the sum of a geometric progression which is infinite but 0<q<1.We can get the limit by the formula:p/(1-q)`. Why this?

Comment: SmallR hits first with probability `p=a/b`, so he wins in the 1st turn with probability `p`. If he doesn't then, Zanoes has to fail (with probability `1-c/d` so that he can retry and possibly win with probablity `p`. So the probability SmallR wins on the 2nd turn is `p*(1-p)*(1-c/d)=p*q`. He'll win on the third with probability `p*q^2` with the same logic. Hence, the probability he wins on either the first or the second or the third... turn is the sum of these probabilities (the limit of the infinite sum). `x^k+x^1+...+x^n = (x^k - x^(n+1))/(1-x)` replace k by 0 and `x^n+1->0` when `x < 0`

Answer (score 2):

- p = chance SmallR hits = a/b
- q = chance Zonoes hits = c/d

chance both players miss is (1-p)*(1-q)

SmallR wins the game (=X) if he hits now, or if both players miss and he wins the game in some later turn. Since it's his turn again that chance is also X.

- X = p + (1-p) * (1-q) * X
- X = p + (1 -p -q +pq) * X
- -p = (-p -q +pq) * X
- p / (p + q - pq) = X

In the given example 1/2 / (1/2 + 1/2 - 1/4) = 1/2 / 3/4 = 4/6 = 0.6666667